# Not getting expected response from winhttpcertcfg.exe

Tags: windows, command-line, winhttpcertcfg

I'm running `winhttpcertcfg.exe` from the CMD window on Windows 7 64 bit. I am running as administrator and I am an administrator on the machine. I used various options and I got the response that I would see if I just typed the name of the program or typed `winhttpcertcfg ?`

I was expecting a response that the program would run and do something or some kind of error. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a spelling mistake in the certificate store. The name is case-sensitive.